# GWT: Eclipse giving "Unable to find module" error when I try and run web app

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, Maven 3.0.3, and GWT 2.4.  I have imported my Maven project into Eclipse and enabled GWT support.  However, bafflingly, when I right click on my projecdt and select "Run As" -> "Web Application", I get the error in the Console pane ...

> Loading modules com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.ProductPlusJUnit
>   [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/myco/clearing/commons/xml/ProductPlusJUnit.gwt.xml' on your
>   classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath
>   entry for source?
>   [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

The bizarre thing is, I have no file `com/myco/clearing/commons/xml/ProductPlusJUnit.gwt.xml`.  The closest thing I have is a file at `src/main/java/com/myco/clearing/product/ProductPlusJUnit.gwt.xml`.  Where is Eclipse getting this and how I can I tell it to launch the correct entry point module (which is `src/main/java/com/clearing/product/ProductPlus.gwt.xml`)?

Comment: GWT would be looking for `com/myco/clearing/commons/xml/ProductPlusJUnit.gwt.xml` if you have a reference to `com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.ProductPlusJUnit` in another `.gwt.xml` file. Generally that would be an `<inherits ... />` tag. In Eclipse, Search->File... for "com.myco.clearing.commons.xml.ProductPlusJUnit" and you ought to find the problem.

Comment: If you still can't find it, post your project's module definition (`*.gwt.xml` file).

Comment: Did you try deleting the generated files in war/'project-name' folder

Answer (score 0):

Right click on 'java' folder in 'src/main/java' and select 'Build Path' --> 'Use as source folder'. Eclipse should then detect module and build project automatically.